# Node.js Webpack ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, openssl, package.json

Orginallly I can launch my app at localhost using "npm run watch" normally. But few days after I got SSL related errors:
- *error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error* and

- *ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED*.

Finally I figured out I have to type this in command prompt than run successfully:
 `set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && npm run watch`

---

1. Why suddenly there are SSL changes?
   I am using company office PC and Node.js v18.14.0 (No upgrade).
   My pc config changed silently? My company upgraded my browser? or anything else?

---

2. Other than to type every time in command prompt, I want to use package.json and tried to add **NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider** like:

```json
"scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "set NODE_ENV=production&& webpack --mode production",
        "watch": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider NODE_ENV=development&& webpack --mode development --watch"
    },
```

Then I can run the app using "npm run watch" without SSL error but `process.env.NODE_ENV` became undefined.
So what is the correct syntax in package.json?

---

My environment:
Windows 10 professional 64bit
Chrome 107.0.5304.121 64bit
Node.js v18.14.0
Webpack 5.38.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Node on Windows has OpenSSL compiled-in (i.e. does not link dynamically) so this should not have changed without updating node. Node18 does use OpenSSL3.0 which has the new restrictions, so you should have had them since Node18 was installed -- although depending on what your app does it might not have actually done whatever operation(s) require the legacy crypto algorithms until "a few days". I don't *think* webpack changes the crypto it uses from one invocation to another, but I'm far from an expert on that, and we don't have any clue what else if anything your app does. Your web browser is irrelevant.

Q2: Although Unix shells (at least most of them) can assign multiple envvars (or shellvars) in one command, Windows CMD cannot. Use multiple commands:

```
"set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider&& set NODE_ENV=blahblah&& ..."
```

Comment: Awesome it works thanks. I don't realize the meaning of "&&". You taught me the correct syntax! I believe you are correct on the node18 x OpenSSL 3.0 issue so I guess may be few days ago I still running on the old bundle and long time no compiling. Thanks.